# "Never run out of fun." Can one run out of something intangible?

Tags: idioms

I want to use 'Never run out of fun' as a sentence. Is it wrong to say this? This is a slogan in a product video.

Comment: why do you think it is grammatically wrong?

Comment: You generally run of consumable things like money, food. But fun is something intangible. So my question is can you run out of fun?

Comment: "You can run out of consumable things like money. But can you run out of fun?" does **not** relate to grammar. It relates to [semantics](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/semantics). The *grammar* of "Never run out of fun" is exactly the same as "Never run out of money".

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, it's fine; try reading the suggested volume at:

> [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574)

in the Grammar section, or try any on the numerous online grammar checkers - they all report it as error-free.

Stylistically, you can try different variants; for example:

> Don't run out of fun
>   Never run out of having fun

Answer (score 0):

Advertising and marketing language is often conceptual rather than literal. The meaning of the slogan is likely that the location, product, or service offers the user many options for having fun, or perhaps fun that lasts longer than a person might expect. This usage is not incorrect, it is just more of a loose usage or interpretation rather than a adhering to a strict dictionary definition.

Advertising usage was conducted on a closed set by professionals; amateurs should not attempt this at home.  :-)